# The ForeignKey Attr on property SongLyrics on type SongModel is not valid. The foreign key name LyricsId was not found on the dependent type SongModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

I have a SongModel , LyricsModel , MovieModel in my Model folder (ASP .NET MVC5).
SongModel has properties

```
 public class SongModel
    {
        
        [Key]
        public int SongId { get;private set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Song Title is must")]
        [Display(Name ="Song Title")]
        public string SongName { get; set;}


        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Let us know who composed this song")]
        [Display(Name ="Artist")]
        public string Singer { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Let us know who gave beautiful music to this song")]
        [Display(Name = "Music Director")]
        public string MusicDirector { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("MovieId")]
        public MovieModel SongMovie { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("LyricsId")]
        public LyricsModel SongLyrics { get; set; }

       }
```

Lyrics Model

```
 public class LyricsModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string LyricsId { get;private set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Lyrics are must")]
        [Display(Name="Add your Lyrics here")]
        public string Lyrics { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Let us know who wrote this song")]
        [Display(Name = "Written By")]
        public string LyricsWriter { get; set; }
}
```

MovieModel

```
public class MovieModel
    {
        
        [Key]
        public string MovieId { get;private set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Movie is must")]
        public string MovieName { get;private set; }

        [Display(Name ="Male Lead")]
        public string Actor { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Female Lead")]
        public string Actress { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Release Year")]
        public ushort ReleaseYear { get; set; }
}
```

I got this error saying
**The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SongLyrics' on type 'SalesMVC.Models.SongModel' is not valid. The foreign key name 'LyricsId' was not found on the dependent type 'SalesMVC.Models.SongModel'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.**

I need help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what the issue is. You need to add a property named `LyricsId` in your `SongModel`.

After that error, you will probably get the same error on `MovieId`.